# How to get data from big Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that contains player data. This array changes according to the number of players. The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Playername1
            [Frags] => -3
            [Time] => 339
            [TimeF] => 05:39
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Playername2
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 7
            [TimeF] => 00:07
        )

)
```

I want to get from this array from each player only the player name `[name]`. How do I do this? The output should be a string that looks something like this: `Playername1, Playername2`
I have not found anything on the Internet or on YouTube. The answer is certainly simple and obvious, but I have not found it.

Im using PHP 8.0.13.

Comment: use this: `array_column($arr, 'name');`

Comment: @Faesal that will return an array

Comment: Use the json_decode() option to choose between simple arrays or stdclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$names = implode(',', array_column($arr, 'name'));
echo $names;
```

- [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column): return the values from a single column in the input array.
- [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode): Join array elements with a string.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```php
$player_names = '';
foreach($your_array as $key => $value){
    $player_names .= $value['Name'].', ';
    // this should concatenate all the player names
}
```